# Bounced mails get Status header

Tags: java, smtp, email-bounces

I am trying to read the Status header of a bounced email. [This site](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/why-did-my-email-bounce-smtp-replies) explains better what I am trying...

The original email is composed by several MultiParts objects, so I am reading it in java code:

```
 private void test(MimeMessage message) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    if (message.getContent() != null && message.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
                    Multipart content = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                    for (int i = 0; i < content.getCount(); i++) {
                        BodyPart bodyPart = content.getBodyPart(i);
                        Enumeration headers = bodyPart.getAllHeaders();
                        while(headers.hasMoreElements()){
                            Header header = (Header) headers.nextElement();
                            LOGGER.info("Header: " + header.getName() + " value: " + header.getValue());
                        }
                    }

                }
}
```

The email part I am analyzing:

> Content-Description: Delivery report Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns; someLink.com
>   X-Postfix-Queue-ID: EC862F00D0 X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822;
>   receiver@email.com Arrival-Date: Wed,  7 Aug 2013
>   13:52:43 +0200 (CEST)
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; noexisting@email.com
>   Original-Recipient: rfc822;noexisting@email.com Action:
>   failed Status: 5.1.1 Remote-MTA: dns; [somelink.com
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to
>   reach does
>       not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email
>       address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces.

In my log file I can see only the 3 first headers:

```
> Header: Content-Description value: Delivery report   
> Header: Content-Type value: text/plain; charset=us-ascii INFO   
> Header: Content-Transfer-Encoding value: 7bit
```

Does anyone know why? How could I get the status header? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn´t find the Status information in the header, and I will take it from the content. It is not an elegant solution, but at least it works. 
If someone finds a better one, please let me know!

Java code:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(bodyPart.getInputStream(), writer);
                LOGGER.info("Content inputstream: " +  writer.toString());
```

Logs:

> Content inputstream: Reporting-MTA: dns; srvvie-mx3.styria-multi-media.com
>   X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 2A1A8F00CF X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822;
>   Arrival-Date: Fri,  9 Aug 2013
>   11:14:02 +0200 (CEST)
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; MAILER-DAEMON@domain.com
>   Original-Recipient: rfc822;MAILER-DAEMON@domain.com
>   Action: failed Status: 5.1.1 Remote-MTA: dns; 
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1 Mailbox
>   
>       does not exist